# How to access all ringtones from iPhone and Populate in UIPickerview?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get accessing all the ring tones. I need to display the name of the ring tones in UIPickerview then user can select and set as ring tone. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apple currently doesn't allow  you to play any alerts in the iPhone OS nor can you access the user's ringtones. You would have to provide your own ringtones for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The system ringtones are not available in the current iOS SDK. If you want that functionality, you'll need to [file an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com) for it.